# TypeScript: Infer type of generic keyof

Tags: typescript

I have types like this:

```js
type GenericType<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    name: K;
    params: T[K]
}

type Params = {
    a: 1;
    b: 2;
}

const test: GenericType<Params> = {
    name: "a",
    params: 2
}
```

When I create an object like `test` that has property `name: "a"` I want the type of `params` to be inferred so that `params` must be `1`. In my example params has type `1 | 2` which is `Params[keyof Params]`. But since `name` is `"a"` I think it should be possible to limit the type of `params` to just `1` without specifying the second generic type like `const test: GenericType<Params, "a">`. Basically what I want is:

```js
type GenericType<T> = {
    name: keyof T;
    params: T[value of name]
}
```

Is this possible with typescript?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you want `GenericType<T>` to be a [union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), which can be accomplished by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) over the properties of `T` and then joining that mapped type into a union via [lookup type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
type GenericType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        name: K;
        params: T[K]
    }
}[keyof T];
```

Now you'll get the behavior you want, I think:

```
const test: GenericType<Params> = { // error!
    name: "a",
    params: 2
}

const good: GenericType<Params> = {
    name: "b",
    params: 2
}
```

You can verify that the type `GenericType<Params>` evaluates to `{ name: "a"; params: 1; } | { name: "b"; params: 2; }`, so you're required to match the correct `name` with the correct `params`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgFXBAPBgfFALxQDeAsAFBQ1QDaA0lCvFANYQgD2AZlBgF0AXGSq1xUeAEMAthBEMA3FDESaYKUlkBnERkYDVNAL5VjdDtz6DFVKqEhQACpp3FR1WlJEBGW55oAIxEAJn9TSio0LnhtYChgCDiROERUTGwcFy0ZbUISUigAeiKoZCQuJABCI0lZeSgAIilGgBpajRzdKBCzO0po2PiAcy4uABMUhGR0LEgs11z8j3FpORFGwLaOxe7eygj+oA)