# TypeScript: get the type of the value of generic object property with keyof T

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

I have looked at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311989/can-i-infer-the-type-of-a-value-using-extends-keyof-type) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501903/generic-typescript-generic-type-from-keyof-t-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342467/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-keyof) that so far have not helped resolve my issue. Apologies if there is overlap that I was not able to extract.

I'm having a really tough time explaining my issue, so here goes my best attempt.

I need to extract the type of an objects value at a particular key, using generics...

I'll try to setup a minimal example showcasing my issue.

I have a generic type

```
export type Column<T> = {
  title: string
  prop: keyof T
  render?: (val: any /* needs to be type of T[prop] */, item: T) => any
}
```

I have a `render` function on that generic type that gets called with two parameters: the value of the object at the provided property `prop`, and also the full object. Right now I have the `val`ue typed as an any, but I would love it if that could be inferred, since we have the `prop` stated as a `keyof T`. So I need `val` to be the value of `T` at property `prop` which happens to be a `keyof T`.

Example:

```
type Car = {
  model: string
  passengerCount: number
}

const columns: Column<Car>[] = [{
  title: 'Model',
  prop: 'model', // type aware as keyof T (keyof Car),
  render: (val: any /* I want this to be type aware as a string */, item: Car): string => (
    `Model: ${val}` // arbitrary for example purposes
  )
}, {
  title: 'Number of passengers',
  prop: 'passengerCount', // type aware as keyof T (keyof Car),
  render: (val: any /* want this to be type aware as a number */, item: Car): string => (
    `${val} passengers` // arbitrary for example purposes
  )
}]
```

Hopefully that showcases a good example. Basically I would love it if the `render` function's first parameter was type aware, since we are passing in the property of the object as `prop`.

Is this possible?

Comment: It looks like we have been solving the exact same problem? (Material ui table?)

Comment: @dwjohnston this does seem to be the same issue we are having. Did the provided answer solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. 1234123451234

Comment: @dwjohnston I'm going to have to stare that one down for a moment. It's a bit hard to understand. But thank you for this.

Comment: If you look at the original question - I think that's pretty straight forward and pretty similar to what you've got. 

As it is, I've just copied in the answer and happy to use it - I don't have my head around it at this point.